# MIPS program seems to be skipping over a branch statement?

Tags: assembly, branch, mips, mars-simulator

So I'm taking my first Assembly class and I was given a project where we get 20 integers from the user and store them into an array and print them in various ways. I was able to do all of that except for one way to print the integers. Here is what I'm trying to mimic in Java code:

```
int userInput = scannerVariable.nextInt();
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
   System.out.print(numbers[i] + " ");
   count++;
   if (count == userInput) {
     System.out.println();
     count = 0;
   }
}
```

Basically, I need to print a user-specified amount of integers per line from the array.

However, when I try to do this in Assembly with branching it appears that the second branch statement is being skipped over, the "beq $t3, $t2, loopF". What I'm taking about starts at "loopE" in the Assembly code below. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Code:

```
.data
  array:   .space 80
  newLine: .asciiz  "\n"
  space:   .asciiz " "
  prompt:  .asciiz "Enter an integer: "

.text
main:  li $t0, 20
       la $t1, array

# fills array
loopA: la $a0, prompt
       li $v0, 4
       syscall
       li $v0, 5
       syscall
       sw $v0, 0($t1)
       add $t0, $t0, -1
       add $t1, $t1, 4
       bgtz $t0, loopA

       li $t0, 20
       la $t1, array
       la $a0, newLine
       li $v0, 4
       syscall

# prints user specified number of integers per line
       la $a0, prompt
       li $v0, 4
       syscall
       li $v0, 5
       syscall
       move $t2, $v0
       li $t3, 0

loopE: lw $a0, 0($t1)
       li $v0, 1
       syscall
       add $t0, $t0, -1
       add $t1, $t1, 4
       add $t3, $t3, 1
       la $a0, space
       li $v0, 4
       syscall
       beq $t3, $t2, loopF

loopF: la $a0, newLine
       li $v0, 4
       syscall
       li $t3, 0
       bgtz $t0, loopE
```

Output:

```
Enter an integer: 1
Enter an integer: 2
Enter an integer: 3
Enter an integer: 4
Enter an integer: 5
Enter an integer: 6
Enter an integer: 7
Enter an integer: 8
Enter an integer: 9
Enter an integer: 10
Enter an integer: 11
Enter an integer: 12
Enter an integer: 13
Enter an integer: 14
Enter an integer: 15
Enter an integer: 16
Enter an integer: 17
Enter an integer: 18
Enter an integer: 19
Enter an integer: 20

Enter an integer: 5
1 
2 
3 
4 
5 
6 
7 
8 
9 
10 
11 
12 
13 
14 
15 
16 
17 
18 
19 
20 

-- program is finished running (dropped off bottom) --
```

Output Should Be:

```
.
.
.
Enter an integer: 5
1 2 3 4 5 
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20
```

Comment: Besides `$t` registers being caller-save, you increment `$t3` but keep `$t2` fixed, they can possibly compare equal in just one iteration.

Comment: Someone should fix Mars so that it trashes all the temporary registers as part of all syscalls!

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't

```
       beq $t3, $t2, loopF
```

be loop back to loopE?

```
       beq $t3, $t2, loopE
```

As commented, there's also a potential issue with which registers need to be saved by the calling code versus registers saved by the called code.